# Unable to persist flash values on redirect in Play 2.2.x java

Tags: java, http, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to pass success & error messages using flash() but it seems that the values get lost since there's a page redirect in place. The documentation says `redirect("/url").flashing` but this doesn't seem to compile in play 2.2.x.
Can anyone give me pointers on how to persist these flash values? I'd appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Are you trying to persist them across multiple requests?

Comment: Yes. Basically the page on which I want to display the message is reached using a redirect.

Comment: No.. Just one redirect

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to mix the Scala and Java implementations of flash. As the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaSessionFlash) for Play Java says:

```
public static Result save() {
    flash("success", "The item has been created");
    return redirect("/home");
}
```

Set the flash values first, then return with `redirect`. Flash data is only persisted across one request however, so once you leave the controller function you've redirected to, it's gone. If it still seems to be getting "lost", post where any how you're trying to retrieve the data.

Comment: My code is exactly the same as in this example. I'm trying to display the message on home.scala.html

Comment: Then post the code for the controller function that renders `home.scala.html` and the relevant code from the view, as the problem probably lies there.

Comment: if (!session().containsKey("loggedInUser")) {
            return redirect(routes.Application.login());
  }
 return ok(home.render());

Comment: Please edit your original post to include this code. Also please include the relevant portions of your `home` view.

Comment: Ah! I was getting a NullPointerException. I figured that it was because of the flash values. I was selecting the relevant part of view to share here when I came across the actual code that was throwing NullPointerException (someone else's code). 
It was resolved by putting a relevant null check. 
Sorry for all the confusion. It's hard to figure out the line in scala.html where the error is being thrown. 
Anyways, Thanks a ton for all the help.